# RailsAdmin field sorting list on first and last name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

From https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List :

```
  field :name do # (2)
   sortable :last_name # imagine there is a :last_name column and that :name is virtual
  end
```

I have first_name and last_name fields, want to sort the :name column by both. RailsAdmin seems to only permit sorting by actual database fields names, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple, you can use anything in sortable that you could use in an ActiveRecord :order field.

```
  field :name do
    sortable "first_name,last_name"
  end
```